# Setting background image using javascript without hard-coding

Tags: javascript, html

Here I was trying to display these images as a background image on mouseover event for div section with id 'message' by hard-coding using javascript function for each image as follows.

HTML code inside body section

```
<div id = "message">
    Hover over an image to display the
         alt text.
</div>

<img class = "preview"
     alt = "Styling with a Bandana"
     src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg"
     onmouseover = "showProperties(this);show1()"
     onmouseleave = "document.getElementById('message').innerHTML='Hover over an image'; show()">

<img class = "preview"
     alt = "With My Boy"
     src = "https://s3-us-west 2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG"
     onmouseover = "showProperties(this);show2()"
     onmouseleave =  "document.getElementById('message').innerHTML='Hover over an image';show()">

<img class = "preview"
      src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg”
      alt = "Young Puppy"
      onmouseover = "showProperties(this);show3()"
      onmouseleave = "document.getElementById('message').innerHTML='Hover over an image';show()">
```

Javascript function for setting background image:

```
function show1()
{ 
  document.getElementById('message').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg')"
}
```

Is there any way to change it using src attribute using javascript without hard-coding the url and change it dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want:

```js
let previews = document.querySelectorAll('.preview') // get all div.preview


for(let preview of previews) { // Creates the mouseover event for all div.preview
  preview.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { 
    let message = document.querySelector('#message')
    message.style.background = `url(${this.src})`
    message.style.width = this.width + 'px'
    message.style.height = this.height + 'px'
    message.style.backgroundSize = 'contain'
    message.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat'
    
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="message">
   Image here
</div>

<img class="preview" width="200" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg">

<img class="preview" width="200" src="https://s3-us-west 2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG">

<img class="preview" width="200" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg">
```

**Edited**

Comment: Want to set the images as background for div section with id 'message'. This code is appending the image.

Comment: In my example I made the div.#message receive the width and height of the image just for demonstration, but if you already have the div. # Message with a height and width pre-defined by css, just delete the following lines: message .style.width = this.width + 'px' and message.style.height = this.height + 'px'

Comment: Is there any method without using jquery?

Comment: The way I did it I didn't use jquery, this is javascript. Having trouble implementing the code?